# Spark JDBC connection to Google Cloud Spanner failure

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, jdbc, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to read data from Google Cloud Spanner using PySpark JDBC connection. My Spark application is running on a Dataproc cluster. I am using the official Google Cloud Spanner JDBC driver as found [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/jdbc-drivers). Below is a snippet of the PySpark code:

```
project = <<PROJECT_ID>>
instance = <<INSTANCE_ID>>
databases = <<DATABASE_ID>>
spanner_connection_url = 'jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/' + project + '/instances/' + instance + '/databases/' + databases
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", spanner_connection_url) \
    .option("driver", "com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcDriver") \
    .option("dbtable", "test_employee") \
    .load()
```

However, my Spark job fails with below error:
[image]

This is usually the standard way of setting up JDBC connection from Spark, or for Spanner is there something that needs to be done differently.

Answer (score 2):

We reverted the scope of the `gax` dependency from `test` to `runtime`, and it fixed this issue in version 2.8.0. Feel free to use Google Cloud Spanner JDBC `v2.8.0` onwards.

**Issue**: https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner-jdbc/issues/1034

**PR**: https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner-jdbc/pull/1052

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to indicate that the JDBC driver cannot find a class in one of its dependencies. Could it be that you are only adding the .jar file of the JDBC driver, but not any of its dependencies?

Or put another way: How are you making sure that not only the JDBC driver, but also all its dependencies are being added to the classpath?

Comment: I have downloaded the jar from Maven as mentioned in the docs and I am using the jar with dependencies, please refer  https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-spanner-jdbc/2.7.6/jar
And I am using this gcloud command to submit the job to dataproc and adding the jar to the classpath:
```gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --region us-east4 --cluster <<cluster_name>> --jars="gs://<<some_gcs_bucket>>/google-cloud-spanner-jdbc-2.7.6-single-jar-with-dependencies.jar" gs://<<some_gcs_bucket>>/spark_spanner_connect.py```
Hope this answers your queries.

Answer (score 0):

The missing class is from `com.google.api:gax-grpc` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api/gax-grpc. I downloaded and checked `google-cloud-spanner-jdbc-2.7.6.jar` from https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-spanner-jdbc/2.7.6/jar, but it doesn't seem to include dependencies, only Spanner JDBC classes are found. So you might need to add the missing dependencies.

```
$ jar tf google-cloud-spanner-jdbc-2.7.6.jar

...
com/google/cloud/spanner/jdbc/JdbcClob.class
com/google/cloud/spanner/jdbc/JdbcDataSource.class
com/google/cloud/spanner/jdbc/JdbcBlob$1.class
...
```